# power shell not releasing dll handle

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a zip file which contains lot of dlls. Using power shell I unzip them and then import one dll to perform some operations. It works for the first time

Expand-ZipArchive "Myzip.zip" #this operation unzip all files
import-module "test.dll" #load the dll from zip file
perform some operations

But when I run it again Expand-ZipArchive fails to replace the dll files because the power shell is still holding it even after the execution. I am getting below error

"The process cannot access the file test.dll because it is being used by another process.\""

The only solution is close the powershell command prompt and then start a new window. But this will not help me in actual production enviornment

I tried to unload the module but still no help. I need to unzip every time because the zip will have new releases

I think I explained the issue in a very bad way. Any suggestions would help

Comment: So, the important part of the process (where you load the .DLL *and then remember to unload it once you're done*) isn't provided here.  Can you show what you're doing with the .DLL?  Why doesn't PowerShell complete and unload the .DLL, in other words?

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).